# Getting line number in tail -n

Tags: log, tail

I want to get the lines starting from line number of the actual file and also get the actual line number in output as well.

I tried 
`tail  +30 log.log | nl`

but above one is giving the output line no. starting from 1 again.

Comment: Your question isn't clear - Please [edit] your question, and clarify it, example might be useful.

Comment: `nl log.log | tail -30` will show the last 30 lines

Comment: @steeldriver I guess that is the answer OP is looking for. You should probably post it.

Comment: @steeldriver cool thats what I was looking for. Sorry I am not in deep in commands did not thought of this :) Thanks.